# jQuery Validation plugin: add validation rules but need to hide message on focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, required, onfocus, lost-focus

The following method is called to make controls mandatory based on some conditions

```
addRequired = function ($ele, msg, min, minMsg) {
    $ele.rules('add', {
        required: true,
        min: min,
        messages: {
            required: msg,
            min: minMsg
        }
    });

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parseElement($ele.get(0));
}
```

And the calling code

```
if (requiredOptions["CompanyName"]) {
    addRequired($('#CompanyName'), 'Company is required');
}
if (requiredOptions["SiteName"]) {
    addRequired($('#SiteNameDD'), 'Enter a Site');
}
```

The validation is working perfectly. But the requirement is when controls (e.g. CompanyName) are focused, the required message should disappear. Basically, whenever the required control focused, the error message appears. The requirement is to show the message on focusout or form submit events. How could i achieve that?

**Updated**

From the solution mentioned by @Praveen_Kumar I came up with the following changes

```
addRequired = function ($ele, msg, min, minMsg) {
        $ele.rules('add', {
           ... ... ...
        });

        // Remove the validator message on focus.
        $ele.on("focus", function () {
            var thisRule = $.validator.staticRules($ele.get(0));
            thisRule.required = false;            
         });

        // Add the validator message on blur.
        $ele.on("blur", function () {
            var thisRule = $.validator.staticRules($ele.get(0));
            thisRule.required = true;
        });
       ...    
}
```

Comment: Which validator you use? if you use jquery validator you can not do code for hide message.See [this](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Comment: Yes, i am using jquery validator

Comment: I think you need to try [this](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a bit of code here:

```
addRequired = function ($ele, msg, min, minMsg) {
    $ele.rules('add', {
        required: true,
        min: min,
        messages: {
            required: msg,
            min: minMsg
        }
    });

    // Remove the validator message on focus.
    $ele.one("focus", function () {
        $.validator.hideMessage($ele.get(0)); // Replace this with the right method.
        $ele.off("focus");
    });

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parseElement($ele.get(0));
}
```

Here `$.validator.hideMessage($ele.get(0));` is a pseudo function, that takes in the element that was parsed and deemed invalid. You have not provided the validator plugin URL to correctly guide you what the exact hide function is.

Comment: @praveen_kumar I am using jQuery Validation plugin.

Comment: @MJK I checked it and I gave you a path to follow. Will the above answer help you in solving your problem?

Comment: @praveen_kumar thanks for the answer. Yes, you show me the way. But "How to implement $.validator.hideMessage" is not clear to me.

Comment: @MJK As I said, I am not sure without seeing a live example of your script. If you can show me a demo, it would be easy for me to do something. Can you provide a fiddle?